# Unable to rename and move files from one location to another

Tags: shell, unix

I need to add prefix C_ and then move files from tmp location to target location.
Here is the script
I am not allowed to place script in current directory.

```
for tmpfile in /home/asmita/tmp
    do
    mv "$tmpfile" "C_${tmpfile}"
    mv "C_${tmpfile}" /home/tgasmita
done
```

When I try moving prefixed files I get error C_/home/asmita/tmp/xyz.txt not found. as entire path is stored in tmpfile variable.

Comment: check the permission for the destination folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to use the `basename` and the `dirname` command to get the filename and the directory name. Use these to combine the values and get the new path.

```
for tmpfile in /home/asmita/tmp
do
    DIRPATH=$(dirname "${tmpfile}")
    FILENAME=$(basename "${tmpfile}")
    mv "$tmpfile" "${DIRPATH}C_${FILENAME}"
    mv "${DIRPATH}C_${FILENAME}" /home/tgasmita
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. First let me fix your script.

1.In below code make sure that you are passing only filename not the full path. Below script is valid only if know the **FILENAME**

```
 #!/bin/sh
 for tmpfile in /home/asmita/tmp
 do
     mv "{tmpfile}/filename.txt" "/home/tgasmita/C_filename.txt"
 done
```

2.If you do not know file name and you want to rename and move .txt files to another folder then you might like below script.

```
#!/bin/sh
lines=`find /home/asmita/tmp -name "*.txt" -printf "%f\n";`
for i in ${lines[@]}
do
    mv "/home/asmita/tmp/${i}" "/home/tgasmita/C_${i}"
done
```

Please note that I m looking for only text file in source folder(***/home/asmita/tmp***
) You can change .txt to other extension according to requirement. If you want to move and rename all files from source folder then just replace **"*.txt"** to **".*"** from second line.